# how to animate this css in 50% width of the window

Tags: css

hy guys this is a simple css background animation script everything is working fine but now i want to Set this background in 50% of the width of the window i tried a several way but i am not able to do this and now i am totally frustrated ... any kind of suggestion will help in my project thnx in advance.

```
<style>
body {
    width: 100wh;
    height: 90vh;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}

h1,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <h1>Pure CSS3 Animated Gradient Background</h1>
</body>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an extra div with css properties

```
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

to achieve 50% width and 100% height.

```css
body {
    width: 100wh;
    height: 90vh;
    color: #fff;;
}

.width-50 {
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #EE7752, #E73C7E, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    -webkit-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    animation: Gradient 15s ease infinite;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}

@keyframes Gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%
    }
}

h1,
h6 {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="width-50">
        <h1>Pure CSS3 Animated Gradient Background</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro your little contribution solved my many problems